# Use javascript code in a specific div of the webform page

Tags: 7, javascript, webforms

I have a website that was set up using Webforms with page breaks. So on the same URL, there are multiple "pages" and div blocks on each page, with a progress bar on top so you know what "page" you're on.

I want to repeat JavaScript code so I was thinking of using modules and/or blocks.

Can I call the specific block or code from inside the div?

For example if I make a block with js code, right now it is showing up on every "page" since they all use the same URL, when I only want it some specific places.

I would love if I could use something similar to `<script src="sites/all/libraries/myfile.js">` inside an HTML markup div but I'm pretty sure this is not allowed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your end goal/use case?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module.

Comment: @Jaypan The website was created by someone else and the way they set it up was with a bunch of markups on a webform. They copied and pasted the same html/js code thousands of times with just one variable changed. Now that I want to update the js code, I'm looking for a better way to separate the js and the html so we can keep the website the same and just change the js code. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @taggartJ, I've tried this but I cannot figure out how to add it to a specific part of my markup instead of every "page"  with the same url since it uses themes/modules